# Get FirebaseUser from the UID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to get the FirebaseUser from his/her UID stored in the FirebaseDatabase, but there doesn't seems to be a method which allows this. 
 
I am trying to do this because I have an option in my app which will allow the users to update their profile, so if I am storing the user's `UID` in my database instead of storing their `Name` and `Email`, the updated profile changes by the user will be automatically updated in the database.

The problem that I am facing is that I couldn't find a way to do so in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: Are you storing the `Name` in the database?

Comment: Yep, but that's what I want to avoid.
In case the user updates his/her name, the name in the database won't be updated. @AbAppletic

Answer (score 2):

Store users with uid nodes so  you can access them to update whenever u want.

i.e. firebase db structure:

```
users
--uid
---name
---email
---address
---blabla
```

Comment: Hm, yeah.
This makes sense.
Thanks